# Some basic questions concerning Stepper motor with geared head/geared box

Tags: motor, stepper-motor

Some basic questions concerning Stepper motor with geared head/geared box.

What is the meaning the reduction 1:56 (1/56) or 1:100 (1/100) or 18/1? According to some charts:

[image: geared stepper motor1]

[image: geared stepper motor2]

How can i know (calculate) the RPM from the reduction ratio? Why there are more reduction for the same Holding torqoue (eg.: J57HB56-03 Holding torque = 0,9 Nm but the reduction can be 1:3 or 1:5)? Does it have affect on the motor life long if i use great reduction (1:100) to increase the torqoue from smal stepper motor? I mean that motor life wil be shorter.

Thank you:
Palko

Answer (score 2):

First thing first, reduction of 1:56 means that for every 56 turns the end shaft of the gear box will do 1 turn. The more gear reduction you have the slower the motor will turn but with higher torque.

When using a gearbox you are trading motor speed for torque. It is quite simple calculating the RPM from the reduction ratio. Assuming you motor spins at 500 RPM and your gear is 1:46 then the motor with gear will spin at 500/46 = 10.86RPM.
In stepper motors it is not so simple to determine what is the motor top speed as it depends on the voltage you use, the driver (better drivers can drive the motor faster) and the quality of the motor. It is also important to know that stepper motors have different torques in different RPMS and "Usually" (but not always) the slower you go the more torque you have.

Gearbox does not affect the motor life no mater what is the gear ratio. Each gearbox has a torque limit and applying a torque higher than the maximum recommended torque will damage the gearbox

Answer (score 0):

To answer a couple of your questions directly, and adding to Gilad's answer:

> Why there are more reduction for the same Holding torqoue (eg.: J57HB56-03 Holding torque = 0,9 Nm but the reduction can be 1:3 or 1:5)?

Stepper motor specs are often a little ambiguous, not the least problem being the translation from chinese language. In the specs you showed, I would guess that the holding torque figure was for the bare motor, separated from the gearbox. So that's a constant regardless of the gearbox attached. Your question suggests you already realize that the gearbox will have a torque multiplier effect, so the combine motor plus gearbox will of course have different torques. That said, the torque multiplier will not be exactly the motor torque spec multiplied by the gear ratio, since there is always some friction, and also some flexing of the gears.

> Does it have affect on the motor life long if i use great reduction (1:100) to increase the torqoue from smal stepper motor? I mean that motor life wil be shorter.

Stepper motors themselves are mechanically simple (basically just two bearings), so it's more likely that the gears will wear or break than the motor. This is especially true of a large reduction ratio where, the output stage could be trying to exert enormous torque, hence vulnerable to either breaking teeth, or excessive wear.